# Bypassing list iterator dereferencing error in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, list, iterator

When I dereference a list iterator, I get an error saying that the iterator can't be dereferenced. This however, doesn't happen when I'm building a Release version and only happens on the Debug version.

Is there any way I can bypass this error ?

Comment: Post a minimal, compilable piece of code that demonstrates the problem. Dereferencing an iterator shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: The error is probably coming from Visual C++'s library debug mode, which puts in more asserts than some other libraries.  You must be doing something incorrect in your code to trigger the error.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to compare two elements of the same list by:          if ( (*it) == (*it2) )

Comment: Then they are probably not elements of the list, perhaps the end() iterator of the list?

Comment: There is a reason you get a derefercing error in debug mode. There are extra checks in place to make sure you are not dereferencing invalidated iterators. It is 99.99999999999% probably an error in your code and not a fault the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to bypass this check. It's telling you that something's wrong with your code and only APPEARS to go away in release mode. What's actually happening is that you're getting undefined behavior that seems to work the way you want it to. In fact, it will fail at some unpredictable point in the future causing you even more grief and possibly many hours of debugging effort.